# Is it safe to replace #include_next by #include in cstlib

Tags: c++, include, g++, c-preprocessor

I've recently encounter issues with `#include_next <stdlib.h>` instruction in cstdlib while cross-compiling a qt 5.8 project.

While I tried to build my project with linaro-aarch64-gcc_7.2.1-r0 toolchain I got `stdlib.h : not such file or directory` issue. I solved it by replacing `#include_next` occurrence by `#include`. It worked but I'm pretty sure that it's not a good way to solve this problem. I've found that replacing `-isystem` option by `-I` in `gcc-base.conf` could deal with this problem but it doesn't work for me.

So here is my question : Is it safe to replace `#include_next` instruction by `#include` in cstdlib ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that you're deep into compiler-specific stuff here. `#include_next` is not standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

Well, editing standard headers is not something a programmer is ever supposed to do. You would hurt your code portability: if you move your code to a different machine (with the same `cstdlib` issue), it will no longer compile. It's worth figuring out what is causing the problem in the first place.

However, it may work as a temporary fix if you want to run your code on your particular machine. I don't know why this `cstdlib` is using a gcc-specific preprocessor directive in your case.